# Why my smart phone does not render Github page anymore?

Tags: css, html, github-pages

I was fine to browse my Github page with my smart phone(iOS or Android), but somehow, I'm not sure what happened that I don't see anything in my smart phone anymore. At first, I thought it's the scale problem but I center pictures and some buttons so I should be able to them in the screen of smart phone. Does my Github page isn't rendered properly?

I use my laptop to browse the Github page, everything looks fine, but just not phone. I have to use mobile devices to access the Github page no matter what, unfortunately.

Here's the link to the page: [GitHub page](https://johnny00520.github.io/TryToWay.github.io/)

This is the picture from my iPhone:

[image: my iPhone view]

Below is my html5 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">

<title>MindScribe</title>
<!--<meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">-->

<!-- Maybe I need. Note that Android and iOS ignore media="handheld"-->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" href="phone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="ipad.css">

<!-- media="handheld" trick for Windows Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="Screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="handheld">
<!-- sans serif-->
<!--smartphone conpatible-->
<!--    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" />
<!--For iPhone    -->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- Home screen icon -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/static/images/identity/HTML5_Badge_64.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/static/images/identity/HTML5_Badge_64.png" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)"><img src="image/MindScribe-cursive.png" id="cursive"></a>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <picture>
        <img src="image/MindScribe-zebra.png" id="ImageEnterVariables" alt="Hello, I'm Stripes">
        <img src="image/MindScribe-zebra2.png" id="onlyShowZebraImage" alt="Hello, I'm Stripes" style=display:none>
    </picture>
    <select id="languageSelection" style=display:none >
        <option value="" disabled selected >Please choose a language</option>
        <option value="1">English (American)</option>
        <option value="2">Chinese (Mandarin)</option>
        <option value="3">Japanese</option>
        <option value="4">Spanish</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not only in your phone, if you resize the browser window to a size less or equal to 768 pixels then the rules you have in `main.css` for `@media (max-width: 768px)` kick in and the content disappear:

```
body {
    position: relative; /* REMOVE THIS RULE*/

    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    color: #545454;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;    
    max-width: 800px;
    bottom: 500px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem seems to be with the `position:relative` rule applied to the `body`, because it changes the page flow, remove it and the content should be visible also for `max-width: 768px`.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much!! Based on what you mentioned, should I still keep "@media (max-width: 768px)" ?

Comment: Well, that part is used for sizes below 768 pixels, you only need to maintain it if you want to apply different styles for small screens (for example different font sizes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One last quick question, you said small screens, you mean like smart phones, right?

Comment: Yes, usually this is done for smartphones and tablets, but nothing prevents using it also for different screen/browser sizes in computers.